# Enzyme render styled component with theme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

I am using `react` with `styled-components`, and `jest` `enzyme` for my tests. I'm having troubles testing a themed component that keeps erroring because of the `theme` from `styled-components`.

My component is:

```
const Wrapper = styled.header`
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;

  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;

  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.main.default};
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.main.text};
`
```

My test is:

```
it('should render a <header> tag', () => {
  const renderedComponent = shallow(<Wrapper />)
  expect(renderedComponent.type()).toEqual('header')
})
```

Jest gives me this error:

```
<Wrapper /> › should render a <header> tag

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous>._styledComponents2.default.header.theme (app/containers/AppBar/Wrapper.js:13:182)
```

Basically, it throws an error because `theme`is undefined so it cannot read the `colors` property in it. How can I pass the theme to my component ?

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Hi and sorry for the long delay ! In the meantime jest-styled-components came out with some utilities.

What they recommend for the theme is simply passing it as a prop. You can also create a wrapper around the `shallow` method from jest to do that automatically. ([Source](https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components#theming))

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by creating a workaround helper function. i got themes object which contains dark and light theme:

```
    const CHANNEL = '__styled-components__';
    const broadcast = createBroadcast(themes.dark);

    const nodeWithThemeProp = node => {
      return React.cloneElement(node, { [CHANNEL]: broadcast.subscribe });
    };

    export function mountWithTheme(node, { context, childContextTypes } = {}) {
      return mount(
        nodeWithThemeProp(node),
        {
          context: Object.assign({}, context, {[CHANNEL]: broadcast.subscribe}),
          childContextTypes: Object.assign({}, {[CHANNEL]: createBroadcast(themes.dark).publish}, childContextTypes)
        }
      );
    }
```

now i can get the wrapper component's state and theme is preseted:
        `mountWithTheme(<Component {...props} />)`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer and where do you import the createBroadcast?

Comment: import createBroadcast from '../../node_modules/styled-components/lib/utils/create-broadcast';

@JimmyLv sorry, didn't check this

Answer (score -1):

Given this...

`${({ theme }) => theme.colors.main.default};`

...and this error...

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined`

... it looks to me like `props.theme` *does* exist inside the styled component, but the theme does not have a `colors` property.  I would look either to the theme definition or to the setup of the `ThemeProvider` for the source of the problem.